# "Troubleshooting PHPMyAdmin Not Functioning Properly"

Tags: phpmyadmin, composer-php, localhost

Warning: include(D:\Xammp\phpMyAdmin\vendor\composer/../../libraries/classes/Html/Generator.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\Xammp\phpMyAdmin\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php on line 571

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'D:\Xammp\phpMyAdmin\vendor\composer/../../libraries/classes/Html/Generator.php' for inclusion (include_path='D:\Xammp\php\PEAR') in D:\Xammp\phpMyAdmin\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php on line 571

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "PhpMyAdmin\Html\Generator" not found in D:\Xammp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Sanitize.php:203 Stack trace: #0 D:\Xammp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Message.php(621): PhpMyAdmin\Sanitize::sanitizeMessage('include(D:\Xamm...', false, true) #1 D:\Xammp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Message.php(686): PhpMyAdmin\Message::decodeBB('include(D:\Xamm...') #2 D:\Xammp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Error.php(264): PhpMyAdmin\Message->getMessage() #3 D:\Xammp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\ErrorHandler.php(281): PhpMyAdmin\Error->getHash() #4 D:\Xammp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\ErrorHandler.php(228): PhpMyAdmin\ErrorHandler->addError('include(D:\Xamm...', 2, 'D:\Xammp\phpMyA...', 571, true) #5 D:\Xammp\phpMyAdmin\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(571): PhpMyAdmin\ErrorHandler->handleError(2, 'include(D:\Xamm...', 'D:\Xammp\phpMyA...', 571) #6 D:\Xammp\phpMyAdmin\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(571): include('D:\Xammp\phpMyA...') #7 D:\Xammp\phpMyAdmin\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(428): Composer\Autoload\includeFile('D:\Xammp\phpMyA...') #8 D:\Xammp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Sanitize.php(203): Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('PhpMyAdmin\Html...') #9 D:\Xammp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Message.php(621): PhpMyAdmin\Sanitize::sanitizeMessage('Error: Class &q...', false, true) #10 D:\Xammp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Message.php(686): PhpMyAdmin\Message::decodeBB('Error: Class &q...') #11 D:\Xammp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Error.php(264): PhpMyAdmin\Message->getMessage() #12 D:\Xammp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\ErrorHandler.php(281): PhpMyAdmin\Error->getHash() #13 D:\Xammp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\ErrorHandler.php(238): PhpMyAdmin\ErrorHandler->addError('Error: Class &q...', 0, 'D:\Xammp\phpMyA...', 203) #14 [internal function]: PhpMyAdmin\ErrorHandler->handleException(Object(Error)) #15 {main} thrown in D:\Xammp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Sanitize.php on line 203

I opend the localhost and tried to excess phpmyyadmin from there but still showing this. I am  full stack web developer. Three days ago I installled composer on my system and ticked to add php into the folder to enable laravel projects and today I am facing this error. Could it be due to composer. Give me complete guidance about it

Comment: "No such file or directory" - why not check that out? Also, how is this problem related to Composer itself? How did you install phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.